# How to define Vue Events on Render Method using createElement

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm using ElementUi NavMenu, and render function with the `createElement` method to make the items of the menu just using JSON with titles and index of the menu, just HTML and JS files, not .vue files.

The menu is mounted, the submenus are shown when I click it, but the actions of the submenu (el-menu-item) does not work. I even try the attributes click, item-click, v-on: click when creating the-menu-item (the documentation of ElementUi tells that `@click` must be used, but this causes an error on `createElement` when the attributes are defined), but no one works, no error occurs, as if the method was not been declared.

Only `onclick` attribute works on the el-menu-item, but when I use it, the method of vue component is not called, and so I have to make a function outside of component (on a class for example), and when this function is called it performs a call to component method (I try $ emits) and an error occurs, because the method of component is not found.

How can I add `@click` (or similar) event on the el-menu-item inside render function of the component to call a method of the same component?

[Documenation of NavMenu of ElementUI](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/menu).

How I'm creating menu item:

```
createElement("el-menu-item",{
    attrs:{
        index:json[i].id,
        click:json[i].onclick
    }},
    json[i].title
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, this is mentioned in Vue.js documentation.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth .

e.g. https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/ypjGqw?editors=0010

```
Vue.component("test", {
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement(
      "button",
      {
        on: {
          click: function() {
            alert('click');
          }
        }
      },
      "Header"
    );
  }
});
```