# How to write vue .sync in javascript using createElement render function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, synchronization, vuejs2

I am changing my code from the template file to the render function. Now I have this HTML:

```
:open.sync="state"
```

But I don't know how to translate this to JavaScript. How to write this to the **`createElement`** function?

Comment: can you share vue.sync live demo or snippet example ?

Comment: here is the documentation https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier I will post a example

Comment: It's just a combination of a v-bind and a v-on:update. Can you do each of those?

Comment: @RoyJ I don't know how to implement v-on:update in the javascript render function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219897/how-to-define-vue-events-on-render-method-using-createelement

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remember that

```
:open.sync="state"
```

is basically syntax sugar for

```
:open="state" @update:open="state = $event"
```

Then the equivalent in the render function would be:

```
createElement('child', {
  props: {                                   // :open="state"
    "open": this.state
  },
  on: {                                      // @update:open="state = $event"
    "update:open": ($event) => {
      this.state = $event;
    }
  }
})
```

Demo:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '#child',
  props: ['open']
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  render(createElement) {
    return (
      createElement('div', [
        this.message,
        createElement('br'),
        createElement('child', {
          props: {
            "open": this.message
          },
          on: {
            "update:open": ($event) => {
              this.message = $event;
            }
          }
        })
      ])
    );
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <child :open.sync="message"></child>
</div>

<template id="child">
  <div>
    <input type="text" :value="open" @input="$emit('update:open', $event.target.value)">
    open: {{ open }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

As March 2021 && From @acdcjunior inspiration I've came up with this solution:

```
// From Parent 
<custom-input
  :open.sync="formData.groupName"
/>
```

```
// CHILD
<div class="wrapper">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="full-width"
        :value="open" @input="$emit('update:open', $event)"
      />
</div>
```

BTW: His solutions wasn't working since `$event.target.value` was undefined.